# Generating function of regular set.

Tags: generating-functions, regular-expressions, finite-automata

Consider regular set of words $S$. Let $f_{S}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}$, where $a_{i}$ number of words with length $i$.

Prove that $f_{S}(x) = \frac{q(x)}{r(x)}$, where $q(x), r(x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients.

I've deal with generating functions in sequences , but have no work with regular sets. Any idea?

Comment: @HughDenoncourt but why it should be $1/(1-f_{L})$?

Comment: @HughDenoncourt is it because : $f_{L^{*}} = \sum_{n = 0} f_{L}^{n}?$

Comment: @HughDenoncourt but I guess this is the major idea in proof.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier misleading approach I suggested. One thing preventing a truly simple approach (from the closure properties of a regular language) is that concatenation of two languages can result in overlapping words. This messes up a simple generating function calculation. Best may be to find an automaton accepting the regular language. Paths from a starting state to an accepting state are counted by a rational generating function. See Brendan McKay's answer to this question on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119294/generating-function-of-a-regular-language/119303

Comment: If you have Richard Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics" (available from his home page), he gives details for this counting technique. (Section 4.7, The Transfer Matrix Method.)

Comment: @HughDenoncourt I guess previous proof was pretty correct

Comment: I'm now very skeptical of what I suggested. Consider a language $L=\{xx,x,y\}$. The GF is $2x + x^2$. The Kleene star $L^*$ is the same as $\{x,y\}^*$. But that has generating function $1/(1-2x)$, not $1/(1 - 2x - x^2)$. The problem is the overlap caused in the Kleene star involving $x$ and $xx$. If there's a way to avoid that kind of overlap, then I agree, the approach works.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt but it still rational function.

Comment: This specific example, yes, but it throws off the proof strategy of claiming Kleene star corresponds to $1/(1-f)$. If that doesn't work, why would it *always* be rational.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt am I right , when he use $(I-zA)^{-1}$ we should represent it like $I + zA + z^2 A^2 + \dots $ and consider some elements of matrix?

Comment: Correct. The matrix $A$ gives the number of transitions from node i to node j in the automata. $A^k$ counts length $k$ paths from node i to node j. Summing to get $(I-zA)^-1$ counts *all* paths from node i to node j. The $z$ makes every entry of the matrix into a generating function. Each i,j entry of $(I-zA)^-1$ is a rational generating function. But, we only care about paths from initial to accepting state of the automata.

Comment: And, since the determinant of $I - zA$ is a polynomial, Cramer's rule implies each entry is a rational generating function.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt number of transitions means number of different paths ?

Comment: A transition is just 1 step in a path. (Every automata has transitions between states, so I mean transitions of the automata.) A "path" is multiple transitions in the automata.

Comment: @HughDenoncourt transition is edge of oriented graph?

Comment: Yes, correct. In an automata, however, there can be many transitions from one state to another. (In many definitions of oriented graph, we have at most one arrow between vertices.)

Comment: @HughDenoncourt okay , then I should associate it with edge in oriented graph :)

Comment: You might as well :) Automata are oriented graphs with multiple edges between vertices and special vertices marked for initial and accepting state.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with an *unambiguous regular expression* of your regular language that is, a regular expression that only makes use of unambiguous union, product and star. In more details, *unambiguous union* is disjoint union. A product $XY$ is *unambiguous* if every word $u$ of $XY$ has a unique decomposition of the form $u = xy$ with $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$. Finally, $X^*$ is an *unambiguous star* if $X$ is a code, that is, if $X^*$ is a free monoid of base $X$. In other words, every word $u$ of $X^*$ can be uniquely written as $x_1 \dots x_n$ for some $n \geqslant 0$ and $x_1, \dots, x_n \in X$.

One can show that every regular language admits an unambiguous regular expression. It is easy to compute such an expression using McNaughton-Yamada's algorithm, which can be found on this French but detailed [Wikipedia entry](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_McNaughton_et_Yamada). Once you have an unambiguous regular expression, to get the generation function, replace every letter by $t$ and use the conversion $s^* = 1/(1-s)$.

Here is an example. Start with the unambiguous regular expression $1 + (a^*b)^*aa^*$. Replacing $a$ and $b$ by $t$, you get the series
$$
1 +(t^*t)^*tt^* = 1 +\frac{1}{1-t^*t}tt^* = 1 + \frac{1}{1 - \frac{t}{1-t}}\frac{t}{1-t} = 1 + \frac{t}{1-2t} = \frac{1-t}{1-2t}
$$
The Taylor expansion gives you the coefficients of the generating series. In Sage:

```
> t = var('t') 
> s = 1-t/(1-2*t) 
> taylor(s, t, 0, 8) 
> 128*t^8 + 64*t^7 + 32*t^6 + 16*t^5 + 8*t^4 + 4*t^3 + 2*t^2 + t + 1
```

You would obtain the same result by starting from the simpler unambiguous expression $1 + (a + b)^*a$.